# Do i need gitlab runner to perform CICD for my projects in gitlab?

Tags: gitlab-ci, devops, gitlab-ci-runner

I am new to gitlab CICD and I am confused about the interest of gitlab runner. Gitlab can already run CICD on the projects automatically without installing a runner. so i need help on which runner is proposed and when and where do I need it ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need it only if you operate your [own instance of GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/product/continuous-integration/):

> 

Architecture

> GitLab CI/CD is a part of GitLab, a web application with an API that stores its state in a database. It manages projects/builds and provides a nice user interface, besides all the features of GitLab.

[image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/ci/ci-cd-architecture_2x.png]

> GitLab Runner is an application which processes builds. It can be deployed separately and works with GitLab CI/CD through an API.

> In order to run tests, you need at least one GitLab instance and one GitLab Runner.

If you [use gitlab.com](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/), then only a `.gitlab-ci.yml` placed at the repository’s root is enough.

> GitLab CI/CD and [shared runners](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/README.html#shared-specific-and-group-runners) are enabled in GitLab.com and available for all users, limited only to the [user’s pipelines quota](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/admin_area/settings/continuous_integration.html#extra-shared-runners-pipeline-minutes-quota-free-only).